# Orientation of the Vector

Tags: math, vector, line

I have a line and a few points and I need to determine which points are under and which are beyond the line. I tried to find a line that is in 90degrees angle with my line and crosses the points but i couldnt figure out whether the vectors orientation is up or down. Can you help? Thank you

Comment: Why not compare y coordinates?

Comment: When the y coordinate is negative does that mean that it will be oriented down?

Comment: I mean forget the perpendicular. For a point (x,y) put x into the equation of the line, find y for the point on the line, and compare to the y of the point

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

You can find line equation and substitute points in thin equation.

Easy case: Let's line is not vertical, so it might be described by equation

```
y = a * x + b
```

for every query point (px, py) calculate value

```
S = py - a * px - b
```

When S is positive, point is above the line, when negative - below.

If your line is defined by base point B and direction vector D, you can determine -  what semi-plane (against the line) query point P belongs to - using cross product sign

```
Sign (D x (P-B))
```

Note that in this case term "below" depends also on sign of X-component of vector D